# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE - Running webdriver IO tests from jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, webdriver-io

I was running webdriverIO test from jenkins with allure integration, after the test is completed it shows npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE followed by the 'java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.getCommandlineInstallation(AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.java:112)'

Already tried with clearing the npm cache, deleting node_modules, npm install.

```
Spec Files:  5 passed, 1 failed, 6 total (100% completed) in 00:00:57 
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! webdriverio7@1.0.0 creditCardTests: `npx wdio run wdio.conf.js -- suite creditCard`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio7@1.0.0 creditCardTests script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\ak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-15T04_16_36_501Z-debug.log
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
    ERROR: Build step failed with exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.getCommandlineInstallation(AllureReportPublisherDescriptor.java:112)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.getCommandline(AllureReportPublisher.java:346)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.generateReport(AllureReportPublisher.java:303)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.AllureReportPublisher.perform(AllureReportPublisher.java:231)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:806)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:755)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:178)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:699)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1913)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:99)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:432)
    Build step 'Allure Report' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed the allure plugin and added again with maven link to get the plugin.

I was able to generate the allure reports but still getting the old error...npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio7@1.0.0 creditCardTests: `npx wdio run wdio.conf.js -- suite creditCard`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio7@1.0.0 creditCardTests script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\arukumar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-15T10_43_02_186Z-debug.log
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[webdriverio7] $ C:\Users\arkumar\.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure\bin\allure.bat generate D:\webdriverio7\allure-results -c -o D:\webdriverio7\allure-report
Report successfully generated to D:\webdriverio7\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: are you sure you have installed @wdio/cli or have it as part of the dpendency ?